# Find rows with same value of a column

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to perform a query that find values based on 1 field if the 2nd field is same

Example table:

```
id, what, why
1, 2, 2
2, 3, 4
3, 3, 2
```

So I want the results to return what 2 and 3 because they both have why of 2.

But the why (2) is unknown so I only what to know if the combination of what (2 and 3) have the same why value. Makes sense? Any help is appreciated thanks.

Another example maybe clearer

```
id, building, color
 1,   house,  white
 2,  garage,  red
 3,  garage,  white
```

I query where building = house and building = garage and results are only given if they have matching color.

Comment: you want select those who have why 2 ?

Comment: Does not make sense. Provide more sample data and expected outputs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a self-join.

```
SELECT t1.what
FROM Table t1
JOIN Table t2
ON t1.why = t2.why and t1.what != t2.what
```

Comment: Added WHERE t1.what = $value1 AND t2.what = $value2 since I require only specific results with matching why.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT what
FROM YourTable A
WHERE EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM YourTable
             WHERE what <> A.what 
             AND why = A.why)
```

[**Here is a demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/62da8/1) of this.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this:

```
select *
from test
where why in (
  select why
  from test
  group by why
  having count(*) > 1 -- Use = 2 if you want exactly two items
)
```

[Demo on sqlfiddle.](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e3e5d1/3)

The inner query finds all such `why`s that have duplicates, and uses their values to filter the rows of the outer query.

Answer (score 0):

Would something like this work:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(what) as what, why
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY why
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

DEMO: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/62da8/5

Comment: `GROUP_CONCAT`? ok, but default value of this is 1024, if it is longer and can't be changed setting in MySQL, will be a problem.

Comment: @mkjasinski: It was just an idea.  I'm not really sure what the OP wants.

Comment: You need a `HAVING COUNT(*) > 1` to prevent showing the values with no duplicates.